# What Does 'vector<vector<int>>& indices' mean in the code?

Tags: c++

I just cannot understand What `vector<vector<int>>&` indices mean .... along with the next line which is `vector<vector<int>> matrix(n, vector<int>(m, 0));`.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int oddCells(int n, int m, vector<vector<int>>& indices) 
    {
        vector<vector<int>> matrix(n, vector<int>(m, 0));
        for(int i=0;i<indices.size();i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++) matrix[indices[i][0]][j]++;
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++) matrix[j][indices[i][1]]++;
        }
        int res=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++) res+=matrix[i][j]%2!=0;
        }
        return res;
    }
};
```

Comment: What exactly do you not understand about them?

Comment: It's a list of lists of integers. And reference of that. Do you actually know C++?

Comment: I am newbie so that explains a lot of things

Answer (score 4):

`vector<X>` means "a vector of X", regardless of what X is.

In your case you have a `vector<vector<int>>`, so your `X` is `vector<int>`. We can read that as "a vector of (a vector of int)".

Additionally, the `&` at the end means that it's a reference to such type.

This is sometimes used to represent a two-dimensional array, but it's a rather bad implementation of such for various reasons. In this case, it's clearly used to store a two-dimensional matrix.

The next line declares a value of the same type as used in the argument,  initializing it with `n` vectors of size `m`, each containing `m` zeroes.